# Facebook php sdk - post to a wall with prompt

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

T'm writing a Facebook canvas app, and I'm trying to post to the user's wall. this the code I'm using:

```
if ($user) { 

$attachment = array('message' => 'This is message',
                    'name' => 'Name of the message',
                    'caption' => 'Caption of link',
                    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/about',
                    'description' => 'Great site!',
                    'picture' => 'http://lorempixum.com/100/100/',
                    'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Do Something!',
                                      'link' => 'http://www.example.com'))
                    );

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/',
                            'post',
                            $attachment);
}
```

So I tested with 2 facebook accounts, and it posts to the wall but without the facebook dialog i'm always seeing. I would like the user to be warned that I'm gonna post on the wall, and allow him to cancel it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the JavaScript SDK, essentially the dialogs bit: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: I see. Makes sense actually... Thank you.